# Find string pairs

Tags: string, algorithm, linear-search

I was trying to practice a few string and algorithmic based questions and i stumbled across one which has the below wordings:

You have a string x of length N, which consists of small English letters. You have to find the number of sub-strings S in x such that `0 <= d < c < b < a <= N - 1` and `x[a] == x[c] and x[b] == x[d]`.

For example:
`x = "ababa"`
The answer is `s=2` since there are two strings which fulfill the above condition:
`abab` and
`baba`.

What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the sub-string S defined by a,b,c and d? It makes more sense to ask the number of possible value of the tuple (a,b,c,d) which satisfies this condition.

Comment: Or `a,b,c,d` are consequent indexes?

Comment: They don't have to be consequetive indexes . They can be but not necessary.

Comment: So `substring` term is not right - it is subsequence

Comment: Can you please share the source, the wording in your post is very confusing.

Comment: The post link is : https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/algorithms/searching/linear-search/practice-problems/algorithm/holiday-season-ab957deb/

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya I hope that you evaluate my solution!.

Answer (score 0):

For the condition `x[a] == x[c] and x[b] == x[d]` to be true we need to consider two cases:

**One** is when `x[a]== x[b]` ie. the same character repeated 4 or more times, we call this case similarities, to handle this case we create a structure to store the character and its frequent, then when its frequent>=4 we have the pattern we are looking for. you can see below that it is handled separately in  the code. the number of possible combination could be calculated mathematically using:

```
C(n,r)=n!/((n−r)!r!) // r=4 here, and n is the frequency of the character.
```

We calculate this for all the similarities and add the some to the total resulted by the non-similarities.

**The other** case is to look for two different characters `x[a]!= x[b]`.

```
X="arbsatbuavb"    Then n=3 (a after b 3 times); S=n(n-1)/2=3  
X="arbsatbuavbwaxb" Then n=4; S=n(n-1)/2=6
```

Here we need to parse the array and look for every distinct occurrence of two characters putting them as keys to a dictionary structure `<key,value>` where the `value` here represents the number of occurrences of `b after a (but no more Bs counted for that a)`, then for every key in the structure we use the following mathematical method to get the total number of sub-strings for non-similarities occurrences that fulfill the condition:

S =  [image]

Here is the algorithm implemented and its results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("TOTAL S ="+ calculate("aaaaa"));
}

public static int calculate(String str) {
    int s = 0;
    Map<String, Integer> struct = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, String> indexes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> similarities = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String[] x = str.split("(?!^)");// convert the string to array.

    //Handle similarities
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (similarities.containsKey(x[i])) {
            similarities.put(x[i], similarities.get(x[i]) + "," + i); // "a": 1,3,7...
        } else {
            similarities.put(x[i], i + "");
        }
    }

    //Ignore similarities
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
        temp.clear();// this temp is important otherwise "cdxd" will count
                        // "cd" twice!!!
        for (int j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++) {
            if (!x[i].equals(x[j])) {// for example if "abcdamn" when reach the second a stop j and jump to the next i.
                if (struct.containsKey(x[i] + x[j])) { // NOTE x[i] + x[j] is a String
                    if (!temp.contains(x[j])) {


                        struct.put(x[i] + x[j], struct.get(x[i] + x[j]) + 1);
                        temp.add(x[j]);

                        //Update
                        indexes.put(x[i] + x[j],indexes.get(x[i] + x[j])+ ";"+i+","+j);

                    }
                }

                //UP I have excluded similarities ie. if we have the following "aaaaa" then we have c(5,4) =

                else {

                    struct.put(x[i] + x[j], 1); // NOTE x[i] + x[j] is a String
                    temp.add(x[j]);

                    //Update
                    indexes.put(x[i] + x[j], i+","+j);
                }
            } else {
              break;
            }
        }
    }
    // now compute the result when similarities ignored
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : struct.entrySet()) {
        s += entry.getValue() * (entry.getValue() - 1) / 2;
    }


    //Update
    //calculating s taking similarities into account
    int simil=0;
    ArrayList<String> perm=new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("String pairs of '"+str+"' :");
    System.out.println("Similarities ie.(aaaaa)");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : similarities.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().split(",").length>=4)
        {
            String[] indxsim=entry.getValue().split(",");
            simil+=factorial(indxsim.length)/(factorial(indxsim.length-4)*factorial(4));/*C(n,r)=n!/(n−r)!r!*/

          //show similarities results:12345=>1234;1235;1245;1345;2345
            for(int i=0;i<indxsim.length-3;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<indxsim.length-2;j++)
                    for(int k=j+1;k<indxsim.length-1;k++)
                        for(int l=k+1;l<indxsim.length;l++)
                        {
                            if(!perm.contains(indxsim[i]+indxsim[j]+indxsim[k]+indxsim[l]))//indxsim[i] is String
                            {
                                perm.add(indxsim[i]+indxsim[j]+indxsim[k]+indxsim[l]);
                                System.out.println(indxsim[i]+indxsim[j]+indxsim[k]+indxsim[l]);
                            }
                        }
        }
    }
    //show results by parsing indexes and calculating sub strings
    System.out.println("NON-Similarities (cd*cd*)");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : indexes.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().split(",").length>2)
        {
            String[] indx=entry.getValue().split(";");
            for (int i=0;i<indx.length-1;i++)
                for(int j=i+1;j<indx.length;j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(indx[i]+","+indx[j]);
                }
        }
    }
    s+=simil;
    return s;
}

  public static int factorial(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        int fact = 1; // this  will be the result
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
```

**RESULTS:**
 Taken directly from the output of the program. __ indexes are Zero-based!

```
    String pairs of 'abababa' :
Similarities ie.(aaaaa)
0246
NON-Similarities (cd*cd*)
0,1,2,3
0,1,4,5
2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1,2,5,6
3,4,5,6
TOTAL S =7



    String pairs of 'www.google.com' :
Similarities ie.(aaaaa)
NON-Similarities (cd*cd*)
3,5,10,12
4,5,7,12
TOTAL S =2



 String pairs of 'hellothisisarandomtext' :
Similarities ie.(aaaaa)
NON-Similarities (cd*cd*)
0,4,6,16
0,5,6,18
7,8,9,10
1,5,19,21
4,5,16,18
0,1,6,19
TOTAL S =6






 String pairs of 'ababaaa' :
Similarities ie.(aaaaa)
0245
0246
0256
0456
2456
NON-Similarities (cd*cd*)
0,1,2,3
1,2,3,4
TOTAL S =7
```

**UPDATED ACCORDING TO COMMENTS**

Regards.

Comment: In an example like this, `abababa` (indexed 1 to 7), does your idea count combinations like 1-4-5-6 or 2-3-4-7 ?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I have updated showing exactly the string pair we are looking for.

Comment: The pairs of "ab" you count seem to all be consecutive but what about valid combinations where there are other "a"'s or "b"'s in between such as the example in my comment above? OP stipulated that a,b,c,d be ordered but not consecutive (meaning there could be another "a" type between "a" and "c", for example)

Comment: Let's take your own example, `"String pairs of 'abababa"`. You did not list `0-3-4-5` which is a valid combination.

Comment: @גלעדברקן You are right!, I included similarities handling in the update, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if `f(a)` returns the number of `ab` combinations to the right of and including `a` then:

```
f(next-a-to-the-left) = 
  f(a) + count of b's to the right
         of next-a-to-the-left
```

And for each `b`, there are

```
f(next-a-to-the-right) * count of a's to the left
```

valid combinations.